# Customizing Material3-components to align with Android's system

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-design

I have a "normal" Switch (androidx.compose.material3.Switch) in my compose project which is styled to align with the app, but there does not seem to be a way to regulate the track width of a switch, without creating a (fully?) custom switch. The width of the track seems hard-coded in the component and I guess they have their reasons for it.

But what I don't understand is that if you look in (stock) Android, the switches they use *are* wider than the hard-coded values in the component in Material design spec? Is there a reason why they deviate from (what I assume is supposed to be) the Material design upon which Android is supposed to follow?